# How to monitor kube cron jobs using prometheus?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus

I am trying to monitor the python based cron job in kubernetes cluster using Prometheus. I am updating the job.yaml file itself and writing the queries on it to generate the alerts but  not achieving anything!
I am following this link but it does not say where we have to upload the queries.
https://medium.com/@tristan_96324/prometheus-k8s-cronjob-alerts-94bee7b90511
Please help/guide.